# Batch For Do Test if exist rename url link on desktop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Why does this not work? I want to test each users desktop for a file and then if it is there, rename it.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR c:\users /B') DO 

if exist "C:\Users\%%G\Desktop\My Link With Spaces.url" (

rename "C:\Users\%%G\Desktop\My Link With Spaces.url" "My NEW Link With Spaces.url"

)
pause
```

Comment: How does it now work as expected? Add an opening round bracket behind the DO and a closing one before the pause. Also for debugging purpose add an echo statement before the rename command to see if it exands to a valid command

Comment: you have a missing `(` in the first line (after `DO`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR c:\users /B') DO (

    if exist "C:\Users\%%G\Desktop\My Link With Spaces.url" (

        rename "C:\Users\%%G\Desktop\My Link With Spaces.url" "My NEW Link With Spaces.url"

    )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for help with your batch file, but I wanted to show the equivalent powershell solution.

```
$files = Resolve-Path "C:\Users\*\Desktop\My Link With Spaces.url"
$newName = "My NEW Link With Spaces.url" 

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $destination = Join-Path (Split-Path $file -Parent) $newName
    Move-Item -Source $file -Destination $destination
}
```